# ASP.NET Core get partially authenticated user (i.e. correct username + password, but not yet 2FA)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

In ASP.NET Core (v5.0), is there a way to determine inside of a controller/pagemodel/middleware component, whether a specific HTTP request is made by a user who has successfully authenticated using their username+password, but has yet to go through their 2FA stage (assuming it's enabled)? So basically at the stage of the authentication process, where they've been redirected to the 2FA token input page after successfully entering their credentials.

The value of `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is only `true` if the user has authenticated all the way including with 2FA, which makes sense of course, since it's a boolean.

I've been trying to get any sort of status indicator of this login state using some combination of `SignInManager`, `UserManager` and `IdentityUser` objects, with no luck. These objects seem to only be available after a user has already successfully authenticated, which of course makes sense too.

My use case is that I'm writing a middleware component which filters all requests and redirect the user to input their 2FA token when trying to perform certain actions as an additional security measure. So I thought it'd be neater to also filter the initial login 2FA (if enabled by the user) through this middleware. If this isn't reasonable, then I'll just have to handle these two different applications of 2FA verification separately in my code, which will likely add a bit of redundancy (but not hugely so).

Comment: It might be helpful to include specifics of how you are currently implementing the login flow and 2FA sequence.

Comment: I'm using Razor pages and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`. There is a whole subsection under `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/` written (not by me) to handle the authentication. In `Startup.cs`, the `services.AddAuthorization` is configured with `options.AddPolicy("TwoFactorEnabled", x => x.RequireClaim("amr", "mfa"));`. When the user logs in with their 2FA enabled (set in the DB), they get redirected to the 2FA token input page. Currently, this also happens when they try to perform some operation that involve their account's funds (e.g. changing the address of their external bank account).

Comment: Is there any progress on this case sir @JethroCao ?

Comment: @TinaWang unfortunately not. I've opted to work around it for the time being.

Comment: Is there any news about this case ? I'm also stuck with same problem.

Comment: @Cozdemir I gave up on the original idea, and just worked around it by leaving the 2FA login implementation alone (i.e. using ASP.NET's Identity Area). Then implemented the 2FA filter for other actions separately, and in those cases, the user has already been fully authenticated. It's not ideal, since there's redundancy in code logic for sure. But at the end of the day, I just couldn't spend much more time being stuck on this.

Comment: i think i just implemented the way i want ( i think you wanted same way also) i followed following article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0

You authenticate user as usual with password and you add claim "amr" as "pwd" and you create Policy if user doesn't have amr claim as "mfa" you return fail() so user goes to access denied path. I think in .net 5 you cannot redirect request inside of policy so i catch request in "OnRedirectToAccessDenied" event and redirect request to your MFA authentication page.

Comment: This way user is partially logged on but if he/she doesnt mfa validated your restrict certain areas from user.

Comment: Nicely done, sounds like you found the way to achieve it. I'll keep this approach in mind when I next refactor this component.